# Ideals in $\mathbb Z [\sqrt {-6}]$ are principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Are the ideals in $\mathbb Z [\sqrt {-6}]$ principal?

I know from Artin that there is a method of trying to cover the fundamental parallelogram of $\mathbb Z [\sqrt {-6}]$ with disks, but I am having difficulty understanding what this approach proves.

Answer (score 4):

No, because it is not a Unique Factorization Domain. Note that $$-2\cdot 3=\sqrt{-6}\cdot\sqrt{-6}$$ gives two different factorizations of $6$ in $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ (try to show that $-2,3,\sqrt{-6}$ are all irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}])$.

Comment: I think you want $-2\cdot 3=\sqrt{-6}\sqrt{-6}$. Correct otherwise.

Comment: @TheNumber23: Yep, sorry for the typo, fixed.